# Call a function on parent component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a Toast component on react, it's show when `show()` is called,
how can I call  `show()` on other component ?

```
export default class Toast extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        show:false
    }
}
show(){       
    this.setState({show:true})
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({show:false})
    }, this.props.time)
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className={`toast ${this.state.show ? "show":""}`} >{this.props.message}</div>
    )
}}
```

First i'd call `show()` using `ComponentDidMount()` on Toast, it's a good strategy ?

Comment: To call show() in other component then you need to pass show function as prop to the component where you would like call it

Comment: What is the other component? Where in the tree is it located?

Comment: Chris - I have a login page, that contains a few forms and the component <Toast message="test" time={3000}/>

Comment: In addition to @HemadriDasari 's answer you can leave `show()` "as is" and bind it the constructor before passing it to `<Toast />`

Comment: Take a look at the [Material UI Snackbar](https://material-ui.com/demos/snackbars/) examples. It's a good library to use if you're interested in a third-party library. If not, then the code examples should show you a good way of implementing what you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Toast message="test" time={3000} showToast={true}/>


export default class Toast extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        show:false
    }
}
show(){ 
  if(this.props.showToast == true){      
    this.setState({show:true})
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({show:false})
    }, this.props.time)
 }
}

render(){
    return(
        <div className={`toast ${this.state.show ? "show":""}`} >{this.props.message}</div>
    )
}}
```

In the component, you are trying to call toast, set showToast props to true by passing state according to the condition.

In other component,

```
<Toast message="test" time={3000} showToast={this.state.showToast}/>
```

**this.state.showToast** should be defined in state of the component you are calling Toast from.

Let me know, if it works.